# »Grund zu der Annahme« – Konjunktiv oder nicht?

Tags: phrase, subjunctive

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden folgenden Sätzen und wann wird welche Form verwendet?

> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme, dass sie mitkommt, wenn XY dabei ist."
>
> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme, dass sie mitkäme, wenn XY dabei wäre."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hier müssen wir v. a. den hinteren Teil ab dem Wort *dass* untersuchen.

> ... dass sie mitkommt/mitkäme, wenn XY dabei ist/wäre.

Den Konjunktiv verwendet man in Deutsch in der indirekten Rede und bei irrealen Wünschen und Bedingungssätzen.

Da es sich hier nicht um eine Ersatzform der indirekten Rede handelt, geht es um die Frage, ob der Teil "XY kommt mit" ein irrealer Bedingungssatz ist. Ein irrealer Bedingungssatz wird meistens mit *wenn* oder *falls* eingeleitet. Er beschreibt einen Sachverhalt, der möglich oder wahrscheinlich ist, der aber nur in Gedanken konstruiert wird.

Meines Erachtens müssen wir hier eine Fallunterscheidung machen.

---

**Fall 1:** Wir wissen, dass XY nicht mitkommt.

Es handelt sich also um eine irreale, konstruierte Bedingung. Das heißt, dass hier der **Konjunktiv** verwendet werden kann.

> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme, dass sie mitkäme, wenn XY dabei wäre.

**Fall 2:** Es steht fest, dass XY mitkommt.

Es handelt sich in diesem Fall um eine Tatsache, also können wir den **Indikativ** verwenden.

> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme, dass sie mitkommt, wenn XY dabei ist.

**Fall 3:** Es besteht die Möglichkeit, dass XY mitkommt.

Auch hier können wir die Verben im **Indikativ** verwenden, da es sich um einen Konditionalsatz mit einer realen Bedingung handelt.

> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme, dass sie mitkommt, wenn XY dabei ist.

---

Die Wahl des Konjunktivs hängt also nicht von "Grund zu der Annahme, ..." ab, sondern von der Tatsache, dass der nächste Satz ein irrealer Bedingungssatz ist. Das leicht sich leicht überprüfen, wenn wir das Beispiel könnte man folgendermaßen verändern:

> Ich nehme nicht an, dass sie mitkommt.

In diesem Fall ist der **Indikativ** zu wählen.

Answer (score 6):

Die Fälle 1 unnd 2 von splattne, decken aber noch nicht alle Möglichkeiten ab. Es gibt noch

**Fall 3:** Ich weiß nicht, ob XY mitkommt.

Gefühlsmäßig würde ich dann den Indikativ wählen

> Ich habe wenig Grund zu der Annahme,
>   daß sie mitkommt, wenn XY dabei ist.

Ich bin mal gespannt, zu welchem Ergebis splattne kommt.

Comment: Ja, Indikativ, denn es handelt sich um eine reale Bedingung/Möglichkeit. Habe meine Antwort aktualisiert. Danke!

Comment: Gefühlsmäßig neige ich auch zum Indikativ. Da es aber subile Bedeutungsunterschiede gibt, und auch der Konjunktiv möglich ist, habe ich das eben mal als Frage stellen wollen.